# How to query list of members updated/registered for a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I have a database table as below.

Id 1 and 4 are old members and their data is updated (as seen in updated date column).

Id 2 and 3 new members.

So now how we can query in SQL Server and get list of members updated/registered for a given date range?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `>`/`>=` and `<`/`<=` operators? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coalesce()` would be a good fit here.  If `[updated date]` is `NULL`, it will then look at `[registration date]`

```
select * 
from yourtable
where coalesce([updated date],[registration date]) between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-05'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from your_table
where [registration date] between '20210101' and '20220101'
```